# Navigation Drawer menu items selected within different groups

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-menu

I have a working Navigation Drawer and having some issues with `menuItem.setChecked(true);` when using groups and headers within the menu. It's not highlighting menu items as expected.

Here is my XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ActivityMap">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">


        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_welcome"
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000"
            android:title="Welcome" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_map_showmap"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_map_black_24dp"
            android:title="Show Map" />
        <item
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_list_black_24dp"
            android:title="Show List" />

        <item android:title="Settings">
            <menu>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_database_check"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_cloud_done_black_24dp"
                    android:title="Update Database" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_map_settings"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_settings_black_24dp"
                    android:title="App Preferences" />

            </menu>
        </item>


        <item android:title="General">
            <menu>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_general_about"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_info_black_24dp"
                    android:title="About" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_general_help"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_help_black_24dp"
                    android:title="Help" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_general_report"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_email_black_24dp"
                    android:title="Feedback / Report error" />
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

As you can see I have 3 menu items, then a Settings Group with 2 menu items, then a General Group with 3 menu items.

Now with the first 3 menu items, the `menuItem.setChecked(true);` is working as expected, and highlighting that menu item. However, none of the following menu items within the subset ("Settings" or "General" subsets) are highlighting correctly.

I read that the `<group android:checkableBehaviour="single">` can encapsulate the whole block, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Any thoughts? Cheers.

**EDIT** - Added Screenshot of the menu structure

[image]

Comment: Any update with this? Still looking for a solution

Comment: Can you please post the screenshot for more clarification?

Comment: Perhaps your issue is the same as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922012/i-am-unable-to-set-a-submenu-item-as-checked) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592906/submenu-items-not-retaining-current-state)

Comment: Try put "<group android:checkableBehavior="single">" below menus of Settings and General instead of the outside menu, as in the second link in my previous comment

Comment: `However, none of the following menu items within the subset ("Settings" or "General" subsets) are highlighting correctly.` What are they doing? What are they supposed to do?

Comment: Can you pl share your OnNavigationItemSelectedListener code?

Comment: From my original post, the correctly functioning items are the first 3 (Welcome, Show Map, Show List). When the other ones are clicked they simply do not highlight (one of the original 3 remains highlighted)

Answer (score 23):

### UPDATE

If you have upgraded your Android Studio to **1.4**, you can create a new project (with `Navigation Drawer Activity` template). Then, you can update your menu file as the following (pay attention to the two lines `<group android:checkableBehavior="single">` inside 2 sub-menus at *"Communicate"* and *"BNK"*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_camara" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_gallery" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_manage" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item android:id="@+id/nav_share" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
                <item android:id="@+id/nav_send" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="BNK">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item android:id="@+id/nav_share_bnk" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
                    android:title="Share BNK" />
                <item android:id="@+id/nav_send_bnk" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
                    android:title="Send BNK" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

And here is the screenshot

[image: BNK's screenshot]

### END OF UPDATE

---

As I have commented, please try putting `<group android:checkableBehavior="single">` below menus of Settings and General instead of putting below the outside menu. That means you will have 2 groups. Hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried that already, however, using multiple `<group android:checkableBehaviour="single">` makes multiple selectable sections. So, they become hlighlighted, but then I have 3 sections which are individually highlightable (ie, 3 highlighted sections at the same time)

Comment: I think you can manually set the others not hightlighted by code

Comment: In one of my projects, my navi drawer uses listview items instead of menu items, and I set highlight background with that logic, inside DrawerItemClickListener :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_vi_tri"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Vị trí" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_xem_lai"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Xem lại hành trình" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_hinh_anh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Hình ảnh" />

    <item android:title="Báo cáo">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_baocao1"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                    android:title="Hành trình xe chạy" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_baocao2"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                    android:title="Tốc độ của xe" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_baocao3"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
                    android:title="Quá tốc độ" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_baocao4"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
                    android:title="Thời gian lái" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_baocao5"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
                    android:title="Dừng đỗ" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_baocao6"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
                    android:title="Tổng hợp theo xe" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_baocao7"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
                    android:title="Quãng đường nhiên liệu" />
            </group>
        </menu>

    </item>

    <item android:title="Communicate">

        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_tien_ich"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                    android:title="Tiện ích" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                    android:title="Đăng xuất" />
            </group>
        </menu>

    </item>


</group>
```

it work for me :D

Comment: This worked for me as well, the missing part was a nested group with checkableBehavior="single". I figured there should only be one group, as maybe a sub-group would have its own checked item, but that was not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use three different groups top , center and bottom. And first top group will have 3 menu items as you have . Then the center group can be same as your "Settings" menu with 2 items. And bottom group will have 2 items as it is in General.

And in your java file you can handle Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu.

```
// This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem p_menuItem) {

            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state

            if(p_menuItem.getGroupId()==R.id.menu_top){
                m_navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.menu_bottom,false,true);
                m_navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.menu_center,false,true);
                m_navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.menu_top,true,true);
            }
            else if(p_menuItem.getGroupId()==R.id.menu_center){
                m_navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.menu_bottom,false,true);
                m_navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.menu_center,true,true);
                m_navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.menu_top,false,true);
            }
            else{
                m_navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.menu_bottom,true,true);
                m_navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.menu_center,false,true);
                m_navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.menu_top,false,true);
            }

            p_menuItem.setChecked(true);
            m_drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```

Comment: That seems incredibly messy for a small UI thing that should be straight forward? Is there nothing wrong with my XML that is stopping the `setChecked()` from working correctly?

Comment: I think setChecked is required in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private int selectedItem = 0; 

  private void setSelectedItem(MenuItem menuItem, int position) {

          mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(selectedItem).setChecked(false);
          mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);

          if (menuItem.getGroupId() == R.id.group_2) {
                    mNavigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.group_1, false, true);
                    mNavigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.group_2, true, true);
                } else {
                    mNavigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.group_1, true, true);
                    mNavigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(R.id.group_2, false, true);
                }
                //Update highlighted item in the navigation menu
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                selectedItem = position;
    }
```

Comment: Similar to a previous response. Seems messy doing this in code programatically, instead of relying on the behaviour of the XML ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the position on closing group tag `</group>` in your code as under:

Look the position carefully and do it.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ActivityMap">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">


        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_welcome"
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000"
            android:title="Welcome" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_map_showmap"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_map_black_24dp"
            android:title="Show Map" />
        <item
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_list_black_24dp"
            android:title="Show List" />
    </group>

        <item android:title="Settings">
            <menu>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_database_check"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_cloud_done_black_24dp"
                    android:title="Update Database" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_map_settings"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_settings_black_24dp"
                    android:title="App Preferences" />

            </menu>
        </item>


        <item android:title="General">
            <menu>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_general_about"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_info_black_24dp"
                    android:title="About" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_general_help"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_help_black_24dp"
                    android:title="Help" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_general_report"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_email_black_24dp"
                    android:title="Feedback / Report error" />
            </menu>
        </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Did you try my answer?